# Operator issues with cout

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading, cout

I have a simple package class which is overloaded so I can output package data simply with cout << packagename. I also have two data types, name which is a string and shipping cost with a double.

```
protected:
    string name;
    string address;
    double weight;
    double shippingcost;
```

---

```
ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, const Package &package )
{
    output << "Package Information ---------------";
    output << "Recipient: " << package.name << endl;
    output << "Shipping Cost (including any applicable fees): " << package.shippingcost;
```

The problem is occurring with the 4th line (output << "Recipient:...). I'm receiving the error "no operator "<<" matches these operands". However, line 5 is fine.

I'm guessing this has to do with the data type being a string for the package name. Any ideas?

Comment: are you using std::string or some other string library?

Comment: Using string.h

#include <string.h>

It's in both my .h and .cpp file for this class. Also using namespace std (although that should be clear by the other lines working).

Comment: Use `<string>` - `<string.h>` is non-standard and may do weird stuff. Same goes for `<iostream>` etc.

Comment: Have you tried including #include <string> instead ?

Comment: @gf: I think string.h is standard. It is not however the .h version of string, but the .h version of cstring, to be compatible with C.

Comment: @Killian: Good point, it may be that a C header gets included instead.

Comment: 'string' is defined in string.h?

Comment: @BSchlinker - you can't assume that anything is "clear" that is not shown.  "Working" is relative, especially if you are trying to tell us that what you have is *not* actually working.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must be including a wrong string header. `<string.h>` and `<string>` are two completely different standard headers.

```
#include <string.h> //or in C++ <cstring>
```

That's for functions of C-style null-terminated char arrays (like `strcpy`, `strcmp` etc). [cstring reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/)

```
#include <string>
```

That's for `std::string`. [string reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/)

Answer (score 5):

You are likely missing `#include <string>`.

Comment: I had #include <string.h> instead of #include <string>.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring `operator<<` as a **`friend`** in your class declaration:

```
struct Package
{
public:
    // Declare {external} function "operator<<" as a friend
    // to give it access to the members.
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Package& p);

protected:
    string name;
    string address;
    double weight;
    double shippingcost;
};

std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Package& package)
{
    output << "Package Information ---------------";
    output << "Recipient: " << package.name << endl;
    output << "Shipping Cost (including any applicable fees): " << package.shippingcost;
    return output;
}
```

By the way, it is very bad form to use variable names that have the same name as the data type, excepting different case.  This wreaks havoc with search and analysis tools.  Also, typos can have some fun side-effects too.

Comment: I don't agree that variable names shouldn't be named the same as the class, indeed, if it's an instance of the class it's a perfectly fine name!  What search and analysis tools are there that don't accept the fact that most programming languages are case sensitive?

Answer (score -2):

use this to output the string..

output << "Recipient: " << package.name.c_str() << endl;

Comment: No, that shouldn't be neccessary - overloads for `std::string` are provided by the standard library.

Comment: You actually don't need `c_str()` unless you want a `char*`, possibly to pass it to a C-style function (e.g. `printf`).  -1

Comment: But- something like this could/would highlight if the OP didn't have the `string` definition that was intended.